# Finding smooth function whose zero set is a given closed set.

Tags: real-analysis, smooth-functions

Let $C \subseteq_{\text {closed}} \mathbb R^n.$ Then there exists a smooth function $f : \mathbb R^n \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ such that

$(1)$ $0 \leq f(x) \leq 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb R^n.$

$(2)$ $f^{-1} (\{0\}) = C.$

Our instructor sketched a proof of the above in his lecture notes along the following lines $:$

Find an increasing sequence $\{K_m \}_{m \geq 1}$ of compact sets such that $\mathbb R^n \setminus C = \bigcup\limits_{m=1}^{\infty} K_m.$ For each $m \geq 1,$ pick compactly supported smooth functions $f_m$ on $\mathbb R^n$ such that

$(1)$ $0 \leq f_m (x) \leq 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb R^n.$

$(2)$ $f_m (x) = 1$ for all $x \in K_m.$

$(3)$ $\text {supp}\ (f_m) \subseteq \mathbb R^n \setminus C.$

Consider the function $f : \mathbb R^n \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ defined by $$f(x) = \sum\limits_{m = 1}^{\infty} \frac {1} {2^m} \frac {f_m (x)} {1 + \|f_m\|_{C^m (\mathbb R^n)}}$$ for all $x \in \mathbb R^n.$ Then it is clear that $f^{-1} (\{0\}) = C$ and $f$ can be shown to be smooth as well. $\blacksquare$

**Question** $:$ Why is $f$ smooth?

$f$ can be easily seen to be a uniform limit of smooth functions on $\mathbb R^n$ by Weierstrass $M$-test. But does it guarantee that $f$ is smooth?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for investing time on my question.

Comment: Does something like $f(x)=\exp\left(-\dfrac{1}{(x-2)^2}\right)$ fulfill conditions $(1)$ and $(2)$?

Answer (score 1):

Without working it out in full generality and leaving some details behind, here is my idea for this. You want to show that all mixed partials of $f$ exist. Let's look at just the first partial: $\partial_1f$. We have that
$$\partial_1f(y_1,\dots,y_n)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{h}\left[\sum_{m\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{2^m}\frac{f_m(y_1+h,y_2,\dots,y_n)-f_m(y_1,\dots,y_n)}{1+\|f_m\|_{C^m(\mathbb{R}^n)}}\right].$$
This in turn equals
$$\lim_{h\to0}\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{m=1}^k\frac{1}{h}\frac{1}{2^m}\frac{f_m(y_1+h,y_2,\dots,y_n)-f_m(y_1,\dots,y_n)}{1+\|f_m\|_{C^m(\mathbb{R}^n)}}.$$
We have that
$$\sum_{m=1}^k\frac{1}{h}\frac{1}{2^m}\frac{f_m(y_1+h,y_2,\dots,y_n)-f_m(y_1,\dots,y_n)}{1+\|f_m\|_{C^m(\mathbb{R}^n)}}$$
converges uniformly in $k$, as mentioned. Now consider the $h\to0$ limit. I believe we can say that this limit converges for each large $k$ to some $c_k$. Indeed, rearranging yields
$$\sum_{m=1}^k\frac{1}{2^m(1+\|f_m\|_{C^m(\mathbb{R}^n)})}\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f_m(y_1+h,y_2,\dots,y_n)-f_m(y_1,\dots,y_n)}{h}.$$
The partial derivative of each $f_m$ must exist due to smoothness. Now applying some version of the Moore-Osgood theorem should tell us that we can interchange the limits in $h$ and in $k$. Doing so yields
$$\partial_1f(y_1,\dots,y_n)=\sum_{m\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{2^m}\frac{\partial_1f_m}{1+\|f_m\|_{C^m(\mathbb{R}^n)}}.$$
This should converge, and a similar but annoyingly long argument would probably work in the general case for mixed partials.

Comment: The function $f_m$ is defined on $\mathbb R^n$ and so it's derivative doesn't make much of sense (unless you meant Frechet derivative which is an operator as opposed to the derivative of a differentiable function defined on the real line which happens to be a real number).

Comment: Let $f_k = \sum\limits_{m = 1}^{k} g_m.$ Then by the virtue of induction, what can be shown is that $f_k^{(l)}$ converges uniformly to $f^{(l)}$ on any compact subset of $\mathbb R^n,$ for any $l \geq 0.$ In particular, $f$ is infinitely many differentiable (or smooth) in $\mathbb R^n.$

Comment: I meant $\partial^{\alpha} f_k \to \partial^{\alpha} f$ uniformly on any compact subset of $\mathbb R^n,$ where for any multi index $ \alpha = (\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \cdots, \alpha_n)$ and for any $g \in C^{|\alpha|} (\mathbb R^n)$ $\left (\text{where}\ |\alpha| = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n} \alpha_i\ \right )$ we write $$\partial^{\alpha} g : = \partial^{\alpha_1} \partial^{\alpha_2} \cdots \partial^{\alpha_n} g.$$

Comment: @AkiroKurosawa My answer is wrong. I'll update it. Another question first. In the initial problem, we have supp$(f_m)\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n\setminus C$. That is, the set of nonzero values of $f_m$ is found outside of $C$. How can $f_m(x)=1$ for all $x\in K_m$ if $K_m\subseteq C$?

Comment: That was a typo. It should be $\mathbb R^n \setminus C$ instead of $C.$ Fixed it now.

Comment: The idea is to take $$K_m : = \left \{x \in \mathbb R^n \setminus C\ \bigg |\ d \left (x, \partial \left (\mathbb R^n \setminus C \right ) \right ) \geq \frac {1} {m} \right \} \cap \overline {B (0, m)}$$ or $$K_m : = \left \{x \in \mathbb R^n \setminus C\ \bigg |\ d \left (x, \partial \left (\mathbb R^n \setminus C \right ) \right ) \geq \frac {1} {m} \right \} \cap [-m,m]^n.$$

Comment: @AkiroKurosawa Edited the answer.